# Spring REST with OAuth2.0 not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest, spring-oauth2

I am working on Spring REST with OAuth2 integration nad below are the details :

Spring : 4.3.0
Spring Security : 4.1.0
Sping OAuth : 2.3.0
JDK 1.6 
Deployed in both Tomcat 7.0 and Websphere 7.

I am able to deploy the project and able to access the Resource as well. But OAuth not working. Without passing token etccc I am ble to get the response from the REST service.

**Controller :** https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/803b4e3aa0428ecbd36aacd86d47d7c6

**AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter :**
https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/3e9baf2c895045db8b71b57b129392fd

**ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter :**
https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/2de1fa631fc172b5d2cb2ccab80cb209

**WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter:**
https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/66473b3e7644bf3fbdcf783a8e73a191

**GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration:** 
https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/799d9153a1413aecbd49243fe2275dc5

**AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer :**
https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/b64a424ee0f98050e3d5c6c58fa53e27

**WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:**
https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/b66c35efbafdc8a64843d78455dc8d92

I am Facing this issue from few days.

Could anybody please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Please help anybody.

Comment: Could anybody help me please

Comment: Oauth not working means you can get the token or you have token and it can't be verified ? Can you elaborate your issue ?

Comment: I have a method which will be accepting a GET request and give response as JSON. If I send GET request it has to give error message like not authorised right. But I am able to get the JSON response directly means without passing token.

Answer (score 0):

Try this few changes :

In [OAuth2ResourceServerConfig](https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/2de1fa631fc172b5d2cb2ccab80cb209) class,remove the method :

`public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` and the class will look like :

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "SPRING_REST_API";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }
}
```

In [OAuth2SecurityConfig](https://gist.github.com/nareshnaredla2424/66473b3e7644bf3fbdcf783a8e73a191) class, update the method :

`protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` by adding `antMatchers("/**").authenticated()` like this :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .anonymous().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested above. But same issue repeated.

Comment: Could anybody help me

Comment: Can anybody help me please

Comment: Could anybody Help me please

Comment: I was able to deploy and working fine Tomcat. Same project I deployed in Websphere 7.

Comment: In Websphere7 it is not working. Any additional changes do we need to do?